# Does there exist an onto group homomorphism from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

> Does there exist an onto group homomorphism from
>
> 1. $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$
> 2. $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$?

For $2$, consider the  map $f(a+bi)=a$. Then for any $a\in \mathbb{R}$ we  have $a+bi\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(a+bi)=a$.

I am stuck on the first one though. Please help.

Comment: For (1), you'll need axiom of choice. Basically, they are both vector spaces over $\mathbb Q$ of the cardinality of any basis is the same.

Comment: Are you sure that they're not asking about the multiplicative group?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom; Yes I'm sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the axiom of choice to obtain a Hamel basis $(x_i)_{i \in I} $ of $\Bbb {R} $ (i.e., a basis of $\Bbb {R} $ as a $\Bbb {Q} $ vector space). It is not too hard to see that this implies that the index set $I $ has the cardinality of the continuum.

Likewise, we can choose a Hamel basis $(y_j)_{j  \in J} $ of $\Bbb{C} $ which again has the cardinality of the continuum (alternatively, as noted in the comments, a suitable choice of the $(y_j)_J $ is $(x_\ell)_{\ell \in I} \cup (i x_\ell)_{\ell \in I} $, which has the same cardinality as before since $I$ is infinite).

Choose a bijection $\sigma : I \to J $ and define

$$
\tau : \Bbb {R} \to \Bbb {C}, \sum_ i c_i x_i \mapsto \sum_i c_i y_{\sigma (i)}.
$$

It is not hard to see that this yields a group isomorphism between $\Bbb {R} $ and $\Bbb {C} $.

Comment: It's worth providing a note that you need to show that $I$,$J$ have the same cardinality. This can be seen since you can construct a basis for $\mathbb C$ from the basis for $\mathbb R$ that has $J=I\times 2$ as the index set,  and since $I$ is infinite, $|I\times 2|=|I|$.